# Quadtree construction from morton ordered points

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, quadtree

I have a collection of points `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn)]` which are Morton sorted.  I wish to construct a pointer-based compressed quadtree from these points.  Reading Eppstein et al and Aluru I am under the impression that this should be a relatively simple task.

Unfortunately the explanations in both articles lack pseudocode and are somewhat intractable.  Hence I am wondering if anyone could provide high-level pseudocode to describe the concrete operations required to construct a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay particular attention to the encode method. It has some bithacks =).

```
import java.util.*;
class MortonQuadTree<E> {

    List<E> data = new ArrayList<E>();

    public E insert(int x, int y, E e) {
        int pos = encode(x,y);
        ensureCapacity(pos);
        return data.set(pos,e);
    }

    public E query(int x, int y) {
        int pos = encode(x,y);
        return data.get(pos);
    }

    private void ensureCapacity(int size) {
        while(data.size() < size + 1) data.add(null);
    }

    // technically the values here aren't final... don't overwrite them :)
    static final int B[] = {0x55555555, 0x33333333, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00FF00FF};
    static final int S[] = {1, 2, 4, 8};

    /**
     * Interleave lower 16 bits of x and y, so the bits of x
     * are in the even positions and bits from y in the odd;
     * x and y must initially be less than 65536.
     * Adapated from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN
     */
    private static int encode(int x, int y) {
        x = (x | (x << S[3])) & B[3];
        x = (x | (x << S[2])) & B[2];
        x = (x | (x << S[1])) & B[1];
        x = (x | (x << S[0])) & B[0];

        y = (y | (y << S[3])) & B[3];
        y = (y | (y << S[2])) & B[2];
        y = (y | (y << S[1])) & B[1];
        y = (y | (y << S[0])) & B[0];

        return x | (y << 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MortonQuadTree<String> tree = new MortonQuadTree<String>();
        tree.insert(1,4,"Hello");
        tree.insert(6,8,"World");
        System.out.println(tree.query(1,4)); // should be hello
        System.out.println(tree.query(6,8)); // should be world
        System.out.println(tree.query(9,6)); // should be null
        System.out.println(tree.query(900,600)); // should be index error
    }


}
```